# saving user preferences of contextmenu in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, preference

I have datagrid with columns and contextmenu is used for visibility of columns.here user can change the visibility of datagrid columns by tick or untick from contextmenu .Is there any way to save the visibility state of datagrid'columns choose by user through contextmenu sothat when user open the application next time then the user get  same visibility setting as done previously.

xaml code:

```
<usercontrol.resources> 
<ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnChooserMenu" x:Shared="False"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBoolConv}}" />
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>

    `<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnChooserMenu}" />
    </Style>`

<DataGrid Name="DGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay}"                       ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"

         >
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SN" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={local:RowToIndexConverter}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Item code" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding MENUCODE}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Item Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ITEMDESC}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Warehouse"  Width="120" Binding="{Binding WAREHOUSE}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Unit"  Width="60" Binding="{Binding UNIT}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Rate"  Width="80" Binding="{Binding RATE,StringFormat=#0.00}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Quantity"  Width="60" Binding="{Binding Quantity,StringFormat=#0.00}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Gross Amount"  Width="110" Binding="{Binding AMOUNT,StringFormat=#0.00}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Discount"  Width="90" Binding="{Binding INDDISCOUNT,StringFormat=#0.00}" />
                    <!--temp used of generic for total-->
                   <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Total"  Width="110"  Binding="{Binding GENERIC,StringFormat=#0.00}"/>
                   <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Net Amount"  Width="120" Binding="{Binding NETAMOUNT}" />

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Save it as a code or xml file, I did not understand very well your question.

Comment: @HodayaShalom I just want to save the visibility state of columns choose by user from datacontext

Comment: If the use control is closed you can save it as data in your appliaction (or as xml file)